# Nesting parallel processes using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Is there a way to run a function in parallel within an already parallelised function? I know that using multiprocessing.Pool() this is not possible as a daemonic process can not create a child process. I am fairly new to parallel computing and am struggling to find a workaround.

I currently have several thousand calculations that need to be run in parallel using some other commercially available quantum mechanical code I interface to. Each calculation, has three subsequent calculations that need to be executed in parallel on normal termination of the parent calculation, if the parent calculation does not terminate normally, that is the end of the calculation for that point. I could always combine these three subsequent calculations into one big calculation and run normally - although I would much prefer to run separately in parallel.

Main currently looks like this, `run()` is the parent calculation that is first run in parallel for a series of points, and `par_nacmes()` is the function that I want to run in parallel for three child calculations following normal termination of the parent.

```
  def par_nacmes(nacme_input_data):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      nacme_dir, nacme_input, index = nacme_input_data  # Unpack info in tuple for the calculation                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      axes_index = get_axis_index(nacme_input)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      [norm_term, nacme_outf] = util.run_calculation(molpro_keys, pwd, nacme_dir, nacme_input, index)  # Submit child calculation                                                                                                                                                                                      
      if norm_term:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          data.extract_nacme(nacme_outf, molpro_keys['nacme_regex'], index, axes_index)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          with open('output.log', 'w+') as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
              f.write('NACME Crashed for GP%s - axis %s' % (index, axes_index))                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  def run(grid_point):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      index, geom = grid_point                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      if inputs['code'] == 'molpro':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          [spe_dir, spe_input] = molpro.setup_spe(inputs, geom, pwd, index)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          [norm_term, spe_outf] = util.run_calculation(molpro_keys, pwd, spe_dir, spe_input, index)  # Run each parent calculation                                                                                                                                                                                        
          if norm_term:  # If parent calculation terminates normally - Extract data and continue with subsequent calculations for each point                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
              data.extract_energies(spe_dir+spe_outf, inputs['spe'], molpro_keys['energy_regex'],                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                    molpro_keys['cas_prog'], index)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
              if inputs['nacme'] == 'yes':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                  [nacme_dir, nacmes_inputs] = molpro.setup_nacme(inputs, geom, spe_dir, index)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                  nacmes_data = [(nacme_dir, nacme_inp, index) for nacme_inp in nacmes_inputs] # List of three tuples - each with three elements. Each tuple describes a child calculation to be run in parallel                                                                                                                                                                                             
                  nacme_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                  nacme_pool.map(par_nacmes, [nacme_input for nacme_input in nacmes_data]) # Run each calculation in list of tuples in parallel                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              if inputs['grad'] == 'yes':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                  pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
              with open('output.log', 'w+') as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                  f.write('SPE crashed for GP%s' % index)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      elif inputs['code'] == 'molcas':   # TO DO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
          pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          pwd = os.getcwd()  # parent dir                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          f = open(inp_geom, 'r')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
          ref_geom = np.genfromtxt(f, skip_header=2, usecols=(1, 2, 3), encoding=None)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          f.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
          geom_list = coordinate_generator(ref_geom)  # Generate nuclear coordinates                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          if inputs['code'] == 'molpro':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
              couplings = molpro.coupled_states(inputs['states'][-1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          elif inputs['code'] == 'molcas':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
              pass                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          data = setup.global_data(ref_geom, inputs['states'][-1], couplings, len(geom_list))                                                                                                                                                                                              
          run_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          run_pool.map(run, [(k, v) for k, v in enumerate(geom_list)])  # Run each parent calculation for each set of coordinates                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      except StopIteration:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          print('Please ensure goemetry file is correct.')
```

Any insight on how to run these child calculations in parallel for each point would be a great help. I have seen some people suggest using multi-threading instead or to set daemon to false, although I am unsure if this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

firstly I dont know why you have to run par_nacmes in paralel but if you have to you could:
a use threads to run them instead of processes
or b use multiprocessing.Process to run run however that would involve a lot of overhead so I personally wouldn't do it.

for a all you have to do is
replace

```
nacme_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                  nacme_pool.map(par_nacmes, [nacme_input for nacme_input in nacmes_data])
```

in run()
with

```
threads = []
for nacme_input in nacmes_data:
     t = Thread(target=par_nacmes, args=(nacme_input,)); t.start()
     threads.append(t)
for t in threads: t.join()
```

or if you dont care if the treads have finished or not

```
for nacme_input in nacmes_data:
     t = Thread(target=par_nacmes, args=(nacme_input,)); t.start()
```